# {0,1}-solutions for integer equations via lattice base reduction?

Tags: algorithms, systems-of-equations, integer-lattices

I would like to find $\{0,1\}$-solutions of a system of equations of the form $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\sum_{i\in I_1}x_i=1\\\sum_{i\in I_2}x_i=1\\\vdots\\\sum_{i\in I_k}x_i=1\end{array}\right.$$

where $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\{0,1\}$ are the variables and $I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_k$ are given subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

I have now been solving this system by reducing its matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then iterating over all possible combinations for the free variables in $\{0,1\}$, and verifying if the other variables are also in $\{0,1\}$ then. However that is likely not the best way. So my questions:

1. Several people have mentioned that "Lattice base reduction" provides a good solution to this. Unfortunately, when looking that up, I fail to see how that would make this system of equations easier to solve. What is the link?
2. Are there any other methods that I should be aware of for solving this kind of problems? Bonus points if not all constant coefficients have to be $1$, then I could add a few more equations to reduce my search space.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very similar to [Sudoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku) type of problems.

**Sudoku puzzles can be reduced to the system of equations that has the same structure as yours.**
In Sudoku puzzles, there should be one and only one 1 in each row, column and box; there should be one and only one 2 in each row, column and box etc.
You can write these conditions as a system above. Let $x_{n, r, c}$ be 1 if the number $n$ is in row $r$, column $c$, and $0$ otherwise; $n, r, c$ $\in$ $\{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$. **You will have 3 types of subsets.**
The row equations are: $\forall r, n \in \{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$ will correspond to subsets $$ I_{r, n} = \bigcup_{\forall c \in \{1, \dots, 9\}} \{n, r, c\}$$ Column equations are: $\forall c, n \in \{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$ will correspond to subsets $$ I_{c, n} = \bigcup_{\forall r \in \{1, \dots, 9\}} \{n, r, c\}$$
Finally, box equations are: $\forall R, C \in \{0, 3, 6\}, n \in \{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$ will correspond to subsets $$ I_{R, C, n} = \bigcup_{\forall r, c \in \{1, 2, 3\}} \{n, R + r, C + c\}$$

**All sudoku algorighm I have seen can be used for general problem - the one you state above.** See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms and http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/meerkamp/Site/Solving_any_Sudoku_II.html among others. Just replace "rows, columns and boxes" by "sets $I_\cdot$", and you can apply them right away. And, I believe, right hand equation values can be different from 1, still, the same algorithms will apply.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That second link seems to give an error though: Forbidden 
 
 You don't have permission to access /~mec/Summer2009/meerkamp/Site/Solving_any_Sudoku_II.html on this server.

Comment: It was working a few minutes ago, and Solutions part I still works (http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Summer2009/meerkamp/Site/Solving_any_Sudoku_I.html) Hopefully this link will resuscitate soon. Usual googling "sudoku algorithms" will yield many more options, if you need them.